# Execute method and webmethod async in webform

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous

In my website login page, there is a section to showing news.in `document.ready` of this page, I call a webmethod by ajax request to show these news but it need some seconds to execute completely. Meanwhile if user click on login button, login process keep in waiting until news load completely, but I want to run login process async, there is any solution to solve this problem?
note that I add async in my function like this:

```
$(document).ready(async function () ...
```

but news doesnt load any more.

Comment: you can make another ajax request for login

Comment: @PranayRana I edit my question. did you mean use two async function ?

Comment: I cant call login method via ajax request, it cant be static.

Comment: why it cant be static ...you can create webmethod for it and can able to do it

Comment: login method use some non static members and methods. I cant to change it to static

Answer (score 0):

you can make async request for news as below

```
  jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com/',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.isOk == false) alert(result.message);
        },
        async: true
    });
```